# Как растянуть flex элементы по ширине контейнера

Tags: html, css

Друзья, ситуация след. Есть форма. В ней есть 3 инпута и кнопка. Все элементы размещены в 1 ряд. Я хочу, что бы кнопка имела фиксированную длину, а инпуты растягивались по оставшейся доступной ширине.

Весь код я представил в codepen. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/whoisdt-the-styleful/pen/oyRqbb)

```
<div class="booking-form d-inline-block">
                    <h4>Бронирование номеров</h4>
                    <div class="form-fields">

                        <div class="input-field-group">
                            <div>
                                <span class="input-field-alt">Дата заезда</span>
                                <input type="text" class="booking-input" placeholder="Дата заезда"/>
                            </div>
                            <span><i class="fal fa-calendar-alt input-icon"></i></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field-group">
                            <div>
                                <span class="input-field-alt">Дата выезда</span>
                                <input type="text" class="booking-input" placeholder="Дата выезда"/>
                            </div>
                            <span><i class="fal fa-calendar-alt input-icon"></i></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field-group">
                            <div>
                                <span class="input-field-alt">Гости</span>
                                <input type="text" class="booking-input" placeholder="Гости"/>
                            </div>
                            <span><i class="fal fa-user-astronaut input-icon"></i></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="action-button">Найти номер</div>

                    </div>
                </div>


.booking-form
    width: 716px
    height: 144px
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07)
    background-color: #fff
    border-radius: 16px
    padding: 32px

    h4
        text-align: left
        width: 190px
        font-weight: 500
        line-height: 18px
        font-size: 18px
        color: #3A3A41

    .form-fields
        display: flex

.input-field-group
    width: auto
    padding: 4px 8px
    height: 32px
    background: #FFFFFF
    border: 1px solid rgba(185, 195, 203, 0.3)
    box-sizing: border-box
    border-radius: 8px
    text-align: left
    display: flex
    margin-right: 16px


    .input-field-alt
        font-size: 8px
        color: #B9C3CB
        display: block

    .booking-input
        height: 12px
        background-color: gray
        border: 0

    .input-icon
        font-size: 14px
        color: #B9C3CB
        margin-left: 8px

.action-button
    width: 136px
    height: 32px
    background: linear-gradient(103.15deg, #0584A6 0%, #3386C6 100%)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовал свою разметку, но принцип тот же

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
:focus{
  outline:none;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.booking{
  padding:0 20px;
}
.booking__form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: normal;
}

.booking__item {
  display:inline-block;
  flex:1 1 auto; /*растягивает и сжимает флекс-элемент относительно его собственной ширины*/
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  padding:0 7px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius:7px;
}
.booking__input{
  display:block;
  width:100%; /*растягиваем тексовое поле на всю ширину родителя*/
  border:none;
  min-width:0;
}
.booking__btn{
  width:130px;
  flex:0 0 auto; /*запрет сжатия и растягивания флекс-элемента*/
}
```

```html
<div class="booking">
  <h4 class="booking__title">Бронирование номеров</h4>
  <form action="#" class="booking__form">
    <label class="booking__item">
      <span class="booking__label">Дата заезда</span>
      <input type="text" class="booking__input" >
    </label>
    <label class="booking__item">
      <span class="booking__label">Дата отбытия</span>
      <input type="text" class="booking__input" >
    </label>
    <label class="booking__item">
      <span class="booking__label">Гости</span>
      <input type="text" class="booking__input" >
    </label>
    <button class="booking__btn">Найти номер</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: По бэму прям все написали! Спасибо большое за разьяснение:)!

Answer (score 3):

Немного код ревью:

1. `.form-fields` должен быть не `<div>` а `<form>`
2. `.input-field-alt` должен быть не `<span>` а `<label>`
3. `.action-button` должен быть не `<div>` а `<button type="submit">`

Что качается вопроса, то для `.action-button` нужно указать свойство `flex-shrink: 0;`